# Query documents with parent and child in same collection MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So, i have a mongoDB collection with the following documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e928d2f6b1431588765bd4"
    },
    "uniqueID": 1,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menuName": "First Menu",
    "route": "firstMenu",
    "icon": "first"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e9291ef6b1431588765bda"
    },
    "uniqueID": 2,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menuName": "Second Menu",
    "route": "secondMenu",
    "icon": "second"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e929fe4d1a9af6bbdc8ad1"
    },
    "uniqueID": 3,
    "parentID": 1,
    "menuName": "Child of 1st Menu",
    "route": "childOf1stMenu",
    "icon": "childOf1stMenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e92b0a4d1a9af6bbdc8ad2"
    },
    "uniqueID": 4,
    "parentID": 2,
    "menuName": "Child of 2nd Menu",
    "route": "childof2ndMenu",
    "icon": "childof2ndMenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e9349cc6d9fb26a836a4b0"
    },
    "uniqueID": 5,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menuName": "3rd Menu",
    "route": "3rdmenu",
    "icon": "3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e934b6c6d9fb26a836a4b3"
    },
    "uniqueID": 6,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e934c9c6d9fb26a836a4b6"
    },
    "uniqueID": 7,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e934fbc6d9fb26a836a4b9"
    },
    "uniqueID": 8,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e93507c6d9fb26a836a4bc"
    },
    "uniqueID": 9,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e93514c6d9fb26a836a4bf"
    },
    "uniqueID": 10,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e941b3c6d9fb26a836a4ce"
    },
    "uniqueID": 11,
    "parentID": 0,
    "menuName": "4th Menu",
    "route": "4thmenu",
    "icon": "4thmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e941ddc6d9fb26a836a4d1"
    },
    "uniqueID": 12,
    "parentID": 11,
    "menuName": "Child of 4th Menu",
    "route": "childof4thmenu",
    "icon": "childof4thmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e94214c6d9fb26a836a4d4"
    },
    "uniqueID": 13,
    "parentID": 12,
    "menuName": "SubChild",
    "route": "SubChild",
    "icon": "SubChild"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e94225c6d9fb26a836a4d7"
    },
    "uniqueID": 14,
    "parentID": 12,
    "menuName": "SubChild",
    "route": "SubChild",
    "icon": "SubChild"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e94410c6d9fb26a836a4db"
    },
    "uniqueID": 15,
    "parentID": 14,
    "menuName": "More SubChild",
    "route": "More SubChild",
    "icon": "More SubChild"
  }
]
```

As it can be seen, the child parent relationship is created by using the uniqueID and parentID parameters. **The uniqueID of any parent is the parentID of the subsequent child.**

Now, how do I get all the nth child documents. (Basically the last child of any parent).

Thanks in advance.

Response should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e929fe4d1a9af6bbdc8ad1"
    },
    "uniqueID": 3,
    "parentID": 1,
    "menuName": "Child of 1st Menu",
    "route": "childOf1stMenu",
    "icon": "childOf1stMenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e92b0a4d1a9af6bbdc8ad2"
    },
    "uniqueID": 4,
    "parentID": 2,
    "menuName": "Child of 2nd Menu",
    "route": "childof2ndMenu",
    "icon": "childof2ndMenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e934b6c6d9fb26a836a4b3"
    },
    "uniqueID": 6,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e934c9c6d9fb26a836a4b6"
    },
    "uniqueID": 7,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e934fbc6d9fb26a836a4b9"
    },
    "uniqueID": 8,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e93507c6d9fb26a836a4bc"
    },
    "uniqueID": 9,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e93514c6d9fb26a836a4bf"
    },
    "uniqueID": 10,
    "parentID": 5,
    "menuName": "Child of 3rd Menu",
    "route": "childof3rdmenu",
    "icon": "childof3rdmenu"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e94214c6d9fb26a836a4d4"
    },
    "uniqueID": 13,
    "parentID": 12,
    "menuName": "SubChild",
    "route": "SubChild",
    "icon": "SubChild"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "61e94410c6d9fb26a836a4db"
    },
    "uniqueID": 15,
    "parentID": 14,
    "menuName": "More SubChild",
    "route": "More SubChild",
    "icon": "More SubChild"
  }
]
```

Comment: are you always looking for the last child of the parent only? the child having the max(uniqueId) for a given parent?  In the sample results, it has multiple records from parentID 5, so wanted to confirm..

Comment: Can you explain better how to get the desired result? Because getting the last child for each parent means the `parentId` is unique but in your example for `parentId: 5` you have values 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10. So I think I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @indybee, Yes, thats correct. I am always looking for the last child of the parent. If a new child gets added which is the last child of another parent, then I need to know that. Please let me know in case i wasnt able to explain it right

Comment: @J.F., the logical point is that I am creating a parent and child relationship between documents in the same collection. Uniqueness is not a factor here. If you look at the first JSON Object, you will see that UniqueID 3 has a parent ID of 1. This means that unique ID 3 is a child of unique ID 1. Hope I was able to explain it

Answer (score 0):

try this for getting the
the child having max(uniqueId) for a given parent

```
db.getCollection('your_collection_name').aggregate([
  {$sort: {"uniqueID" : 1}},
  {$group: {
     _id: "$parentID",
      children: { $push:  "$$ROOT"  },  
   }},
   
   {$match: {_id : {$gt: 0}}}, //exclude results where parentID was 0
   
   {
       $project: {_id: 0, "parentID" : 1, "lastChild" : {$last: "$children"}}
   },
   
   {$replaceRoot: {"newRoot" : "$lastChild"}}
])
```

Comment: Sorry. Didnt work. Not giving the child in some cases.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are really exepecting uniqueID 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,  as you have posted in the question - even though they all belong to the same parent? If that is true, I don't understand what it means by "the last child of any parent".

Comment: Thats correct. Request you to please imagine this as a menu. Thats the core thing we are trying to use this data structure for. The last child of any parent means that inside every menu, there is a submenu which we want to show. Hope that helps